# Which codecs are supported by ffmpeg libraries in system?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, codec

I have Linux server/workstation box which had ffmpeg compilled for it some time ago. Now one type of library for internet communication does not seem to work on one of the endpoints. I think that real problem is related to codec used by the endpoint. Only thing I have to do is recompile ffmpeg if that is the case.

However I don't know how to list all codecs compiled in ffmpeg libraries and if it is really my problem. Any ideas how to list all codecs used/provided by ffmpeg?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -codecs ## will get you all the codecs
ffmpeg -encoders ## will get you all the encoders
ffmpeg -decoders ## will get you all the decoders
```

The latter two may not be available in older versions of ffmpeg. All of these output to STDOUT, so you'll be able to grep them if you want to check for a specific thing, or pipe it into less or whatever.

On a related note, you can also do:

```
ffmpeg -help encoder=libx264
```

to get detailed information on a specific encoder.

Comment: Yay problem is blidingly clear: `ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx264.so.114: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` libx264 linking problems. Thanks anyway for help.

Answer (score 2):

To list the available codecs just use

```
ffmpeg -codecs
```

which gives you a nice list:

```
(...)
Codecs:
 D..... = Decoding supported
 .E.... = Encoding supported
 ..V... = Video codec
 ..A... = Audio codec
 ..S... = Subtitle codec
 ...S.. = Supports draw_horiz_band
 ....D. = Supports direct rendering method 1
 .....T = Supports weird frame truncation
 ------
 D V D  4xm             4X Movie
 D V D  8bps            QuickTime 8BPS video
 D A D  8svx_exp        8SVX exponent
(...)
```